# How to create zookeeper auth mechanism?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-zookeeper, digest-authentication

i'm trying to create an acl for a node:

```
    ZooKeeper client = new ZooKeeper("host:port/rootNode", 3000, null);
    ACL acl = new ACL(Perms.CREATE,new Id("digest","user:pass"));
    client.create("/testNode",new String("test").getBytes(), Arrays.asList(acl), CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
    client.close();
```

Then i try to access to that node and create a node under "testNode":

```
    ZooKeeper client = new ZooKeeper(" host:port/rootNode", 3000, null);
    client.addAuthInfo("digest", new String("user:pass").getBytes());       
    Stat stat;
    try {
        stat = client.exists("/testNode", false);
        if(stat!=null){
            client.create("/testNode/clientTest", new String("clienttest").getBytes(),Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
        }
    } catch (KeeperException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.close();
```

but it gives me:

```
    org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /testNode/clientTest
```

when i'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The document says:

> digest uses a username:password string to generate MD5 hash which is
>   then used as an ACL ID identity. Authentication is done by sending the
>   username:password in clear text. When used in the ACL the expression
>   will be the username:base64 encoded SHA1 password digest.

So, when creating the node, the ACL expression can not be just `user:pass`, it must be encoded. 
Do this:

```
String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest("user:pass".getBytes()));
ACL acl = new ACL(ZooDefs.Perms.ALL, new Id("digest","user:" + s));
```

Btw, the document is kind of wrong. Because according to that, you should `digest("pass")`. But that won't work, you must hash the whole string `digest("user:pass")`